# Creating a custom Feature/plugin in SuiteCommerce Advanced?

Tags: plugins, module, netsuite, suitecommerce

My question is regarding Netsuite SCA/Sitebuilder website related. I would like to know if anyone has tried making custom feature for website in netsuite UI? for eg: we have "Add to cart button show for facet result" checkbox in Suitecommerce configuration OR we have feature like "Password protect entire website" feature in shopping tab of setup website, where if we enable/disable that button it reflect on website directly, just like this if anyone want to create their own functionality and bundle it or create module which can be used in general for other website of netsuite also, How can we do this or is it possible or not? Can we make Reusable module in Netsuite for website purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done it almost all point mentioned above, everything is possible in Netsuite SCA, I am not sure about site builder, But SCA is grt customization capabilities. Do check out my other answer on StackOverflow. Let me know if you have more question.

Comment: Hi Anup, Thanks for your reply. How it can be done. Eg: if i take a simple example like there is my custom Search Box that will appear on website if we enable a option from netsuite Backend UI. Then what will be the process to deploy such module in netsuite and create such option/button in backend (like setup website or any place in UI of netsuite)? Please suggest. thanks again ! i will surely check ur other answers.

Comment: You can not create any option/button under Setup-->SCA-->Setup your site, but you can easily add checkout in configuration i.e Setup-->SCA-->Configuration. and you can access this checkout value in form of T/F on front end.
Steps for Vinson Release:
1. Go To Any Module folder like home page
2. Create Configuration forlder 
3. Under that create json file for example searchbox.json
4.Create json structure as per your requirement, you can refer  this file, Modules\suitecommerce\Home@2.1.0\Configuration\Home.json
5. simply deploy your code, once deployed access using SC.CONFIGURATION